# Using Apache2: How to exclude a single subfolder form beeing redirectet to HTTPS?

Tags: apache, http, redirect, https, subdirectory

I use "letsencrypt" and so all my http: requests are now redirected to https using the following rule at the end of the apache config file:

....

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mysubdomain.mydomain.eu [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mail.mydomain.eu [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mydomain.eu [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.mydomain.eu
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
```

Now I wonder, how I can exclude a single file in a subfolder (or better the  whole subdirectory) from this "redirection" (lets call it "http://mydomain.eu/mysubfolder/mysubpage.php" or simply "http://mydomain.eu/mysubfolder").
I use this, because I have a fixed URL in an old code, which does not work when the page is redirected from http: to https:

Answer (score 0):

Just add another condition above `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mysubfolder
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer. I added the mentioned line above the line "RewriteRule ..." but there is no effect. Do I have to add some [OR] or [AND] to the line before?